# How to zip images from a folder with specific criteria

Tags: php, xml, file, zip

I have to zip images from a folder with the following criteria:
-> Only zip 30 images with the latest publish date and with stock > 30.

Here's how I do:
- First I need to get the names of the images from an xml file.
- I check whether an image with the name does exist or not.
- If an image with the name does exist in the folder, i put that image to the zip file

the code is here:

```
<?php
$document = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$document->formatOutput = true;
$document->load('after_filter_xml.xml');

getlatestproductimage ($document);

function getlatestproductimage($doc) {
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    $zipname = 'latestimage.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item) {
        $url = $xpath->evaluate('string(g:promotion_image_url)', $item);
        $name = basename($url);
        $stock = $xpath->evaluate('string(g:avail)', $item);
        $category= $xpath->evaluate('string(g:main_category_name)', $item);

        if ($zip->numFiles < 30) {
            if($category== 'Jeans' && $stock >= 30) {
                if (file_exists('images/promo_images'.$name)) {
                    $put_file = file_get_contents($name);
                    $zip->addFromString($name, $put_file);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    $zip->close();
}

?>
```

I'm trying to do that but it doesn't give me any result. Is there something that I'm wrong with the code? Thanks for the help

Comment: `<? php` need to be `<?php` and try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` just after it and check your code again by running it. If any error is there it will come-out

Comment: Welp, I've added the `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` but it doesn't show any error

Comment: Share the sample xml and filename list as attachment